# How to use AND , OR , () clauses in Solr query?

Tags: solr

I need a Solr query with AND, (), OR, clauses, something like this

```
search +TYPE:"ecmcndgostst:nd_gost_standards"  +@ecmcnddoc\:doc_kind_cp_ecmcdict_value:"gost_gost" AND (+@ecmcnddoc\:biblio_fond:"standard" OR +@ecmcnddoc\:biblio_fond:"regulations")
```

(it's just an example this query doesn't work).
It is an attempt to re-write in Solr the following CMIS query:

```
SELECT p.cmis:objectId  FROM  ecmcnddoc:common_attr_aspect  AS d JOIN ecmcnddoc:biblio_attr_aspect AS p ON d.cmis:objectId = p.cmis:objectId JOIN ecmcnddoc:reg_attr_aspect AS s  ON s.cmis:objectId = p.cmis:objectId JOIN ecmcnddoc:spec_attr_aspect AS asp ON asp.cmis:objectId = p.cmis:objectId WHERE p.cmis:objectTypeId='D:ecmcndgostst:nd_gost_standards' AND d.ecmcnddoc:doc_kind_cp_ecmcdict_value='gost_gost' AND (p.ecmcnddoc:biblio_fond='standard' OR p.ecmcnddoc:biblio_fond='regulations')
```

Could you help me with Solr ?

Comment: hows your data indexed into solr? whats the structure of your data?

Comment: If your terms are not required (i.e. with `+` in front of the field names in the OR statements) - why are they present? You don't need those qualifiers ("required") when you're using boolean syntax. `TYPE:"ecmcndgostst:nd_gost_standards" AND @ecmcnddoc\:doc_kind_cp_ecmcdict_value:"gost_gost" AND (@ecmcnddoc\:biblio_fond:"standard" OR @ecmcnddoc\:biblio_fond:"regulations")` should be parsed in the manner you want, shouldn't it?